# NodeJS: Ensuring multiple users aren't assigned the same ID numbers for their items

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I apologize if the title makes no sense, allow me to explain.

I am designing a NodeJS application that allows users to submit a list of items to a server. When the list is submitted by the user, the server assigns each item a unique ID and then returns the newly generated list of items with their assigned IDs. In the unlikely event multiple users submit a list at the same time to the server, I want to ensure that users won't have overlapping IDs assigned.

e.g.

UserA submits items `[ a, b, c ]`, the server returns with their list in the form: `[ {item: a, id: 1}, {item: b, id: 2}, {item: c, id: 3} ]`

UserB submits items `[ d, e, f ]`, the server returns with their list in the form: `[ {item: d, id: 1}, {item: e, id: 2}, {item: f, id: 3} ]`

Both users have submitted their lists to the server at the same time and have accidentally received the same IDs for their items.

Am I being too paranoid that this scenario could happen or is there a way to avoid this even if my concerns are unnecessary?

Comment: Generally a database is responsible for assigning IDs to records. Assuming that you're using a database this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid

Comment: if you're generating yourself, hash in something that's unique to the user as well as the time and the list, like the user's id.

Comment: how are you generating ids? how are you storing them? do you want ids to be sequential?

Comment: @Max The ID's are just a subset of numbers (e.g., 1 - 1000). They are being stored in MongoDB, but effectively the user will submit an indeterminate amount of items that will then claim a set of IDs equal to the number of items submitted (e.g., if the user submits 11 items, IDs 1 - 11 will be claimed for those items). Yes they need to be sequential.

Comment: you'll need to have Mongo create documents for each of new items with sequential ids assigned to each. This is the only way to make sure your ids are unique and your app is stateless (e.g. will not lose count of ids on server restart)